# Getting second and third highest value in a dictionary

Tags: dictionary

```
dict = {'a':5 , 'b':4, 'c':3, 'd':3, 'e':1}
```

Second is 'b' with 4 times. Joint third are 'c' and 'd' with 3 times. As the dictionary changes over time, say, 'f' is added with a value of 3, then third will be 'c', 'd', and 'f' with 3 times.

Comment: If you used a `collections.Counter` you'd get the `most_common` method...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just create a gencomp of tuple value,key and sort it. Print items

```
d = {'a':5 , 'b':4, 'c':3, 'd':3, 'e':1}

x = sorted(((v,k) for k,v in d.items()))
print(x[-2][1])
print(x[-3][1])
```

result:

```
b
d
```

(would fail if dict doesn't have at least 3 items)

Or directly with `key` parameter (avoids data reordering)

```
x = sorted(d.items(),key=(lambda i: i[1]))
print(x[-2][0])
print(x[-3][0])
```

result:

```
b
d
```

BTW avoid using `dict` as a variable.

EDIT: since there are several identical values, you may want to get the 2 second best values and the associated letters. You have to do it differently. I'd create a default list using key as value and store in a list, then sort it as done in the above code:

```
import collections

d = {'a':5 , 'b':4, 'c':3, 'd':3, 'e':1}

dd = collections.defaultdict(list)

for k,v in d.items():
    dd[v].append(k)

x = sorted(dd.items())

print(x[-2])
print(x[-3])
```

result:

```
(4, ['b'])
(3, ['c', 'd'])
```

Comment: So output of x is [('a',5, 'b',4)] or something like that. By using [-2][1], you are grab the second last index and the [1] is the value?

Comment: I need to also get the key that corresponds with the value and also if multiple keys have the same occurrence, they must also be printed.

Comment: I have added something which does what you want. Slightly different technique.

Comment: Thanks. You're awesome!

Comment: If the dictionary is: `{'a': 1000, 'b': 3000, 'c': 100, 'd': 3000}`, this way returns b as the second largest value.