# How to find nth smallest value in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, rank

If I have a Python dictionary, how do I get the key to the entry which contains the nth minimum value?

Given the input:

```
input = {'Apple':1, 'Banana':3, 'Orange':9,
 'Watermelon':5, 'Mango': 4, 'Peach': 4,'Blueberry':10}

def return_smallest_key(input, n):
```

```
if n = 3 
It should return 'Mango', 'Peach'
```

Also, if someone could introduce two different solutions,

Solution one: n = 6, return Blueberry (since Mango and Peach both equal to 4, we count them in the rank as 1,2,3,3,4,5,6)

Solution two: n = 6 return Orange (Count Mango and Peach in the rank as 1,2,3,3,5,6,7)

Comment: What do "(count Mango and Peach as 2)" and "(Count Mango and Peach as 1)" mean?

Comment: Also, what does `n` do?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark it seems that when they are tied (same values) assume they are count as a single item

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark You mean the n in "nth smallest"?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the feedback, I just eddied my question.

Comment: Sounds pretty similar to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571876/getting-second-and-third-highest-value-in-a-dictionary

Comment: @AndrewRyan Got it, thanks. In that case, what would be the solution for `n = 4` in the second case? @YumengXu

Comment: @Sahil -- slight difference in that solution doesn't return both 3rd smallest i.e. both 'Mango" and "Peach" with value 4.  Also, what would be the 4th smallest?

Comment: @
BrokenBenchmark I don't want to return anything for n = 4. Consider it is a Sports game, we have two tie player rank both at 1st. then the following player should take the 3rd place, rather than the second place. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution one:

```
def return_smallest_key(dictionary, n):
    ser = pd.Series(dictionary).rank(method='dense')
    return list(ser[ser==float(n)].index)

return_smallest_key(input, 6)
```

Solution two:

```
def return_smallest_key(dictionary, n):
    ser = pd.Series(dictionary).rank(method='first')
    return list(ser[ser==float(n)].index)

return_smallest_key(input, 6)
```

Comment: Need to change input to dictionary in your function definitions.  Also, should correct poster's use of input as a global variable name (i.e. bad practice).

Comment: You are absolutely right, I was changing names before posting and missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach**

- Create sorted key, value pairs of dictionary items
- Group pairs by value
- Find rank by counting items from lowest value group until we get the desired rank

Note: input should never be used as a global variable names since it conflicts with builtin function

**Code**

```
from itertools import groupby

# input values (shouldn't use input as variable name in Python)
data = {'Apple':1, 
        'Banana':3, 
        'Orange':9, 
        'Watermelon':5, 
        'Mango': 4, 
        'Peach': 4,
        'Blueberry':10}

def solution_one(d, rank):
    
    ' Sort dictionary value, creating a list of tuples of key, value pairs '
    values = sorted(d.items(), key = lambda kv: kv[1])
   
    # Group tuples by value
    # Determine rank by counting pairs until we reach desired rank
    count = 0
    for k, v in groupby(values, key = lambda kv: kv[1]):
        v = list(v)
        if count + 1 == rank:
            return [x[0] for x in v]  # List of values at this rank
        elif count > rank:
            return    # Will not have any values that match rank
        
        count += 1               # update count of tuples encountered
        
def solution_two(d, rank):
    
    ' Sort dictionary value, creating a list of tuples of key, value pairs '
    values = sorted(d.items(), key = lambda kv: kv[1])
   
    # Group tuples by value
    # Determine rank by counting pairs until we reach desired rank
    count = 0
    for k, v in groupby(values, key = lambda kv: kv[1]):
        v = list(v)
        if count + 1 == rank:
            return [x[0] for x in v]  # List of values at this rank
        elif count > rank:
            return    # Will not have any values that match rank
        
        count += len(v)               # update count of tuples encountered
```

**Test**

Test solutions 1 & 2 by displaying ranks 1 through 8

```
print('# Ranks for Solution 1')
for r in range(1, 9):
    print(r, solution_one(data, r))
    
print()
print('# Ranks for Solution 2')
for r in range(1, 9):
    print(r, solution_two(data, r))
```

**Output**

```
# Ranks for Solution 1
1 ['Apple']
2 ['Banana']
3 ['Mango', 'Peach']
4 ['Watermelon']
5 ['Orange']
6 ['Blueberry']
7 None
8 None

# Ranks for Solution 2
1 ['Apple']
2 ['Banana']
3 ['Mango', 'Peach']
4 None
5 ['Watermelon']
6 ['Orange']
7 ['Blueberry']
8 None
```